# How to make inner join on this query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT hit.timestamp,hit.id,config.Name,hit.meter_id,levels.LevelName, pos.sm_pos , hit.hit_value 
FROM pos,hit,controllers,levels,config 
WHERE hit.id=config.id
AND hit.meter_id=levels.id 
AND pos.id=hit.id
AND pos.controller_id=controllers.id;
```

How to make an inner join query from this? With aliases or something? I was looking and I can't find anything for multiple table query.

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are joining tables is outdated now. It was used eartlier, now we use keyword like `INNER/NATURAL/LEFT OUTER/RIGHT OUTER/CROSS` etc. to join tables on basis of requirement.

[Refer Join in Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT hit.timestamp, 
       hit.id, 
       config.Name, 
       hit.meter_id, 
       levels.LevelName, 
       pos.sm_pos, 
       hit.hit_value 
FROM   hit 
       INNER JOIN config 
               ON hit.id = config.id 
       INNER JOIN levels 
               ON hit.meter_id = levels.id 
       INNER JOIN POS 
               ON pos.id = hit.id 
       INNER JOIN controllers 
               ON pos.controller_id = controllers.id;
```

Note : The query posted by you is according the SQL-89 standard and the second posted by me is according to SQL-92.
The SQL-92 standard introduced `INNER JOIN .. ON` and `OUTER JOIN .. ON` in order to replace the more complex(?) syntax of SQL-89.

Comment: one more question. your code is working correctly in mysql. but when I try it in php I am getting an error that there is undefined index in each column except first one. So the first one goes trough and others are failing. Any idea?

Comment: I got it posted on stackoverflow as question so people are working on it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reformat your query, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
    H.timestamp,
    H.id,
    F.Name,
    H.meter_id,
    L.LevelName, 
    P.sm_pos, 
    H.hit_value 
FROM pos AS P
INNER JOIN controllers AS C ON P.controller_id = C.id
INNER JOIN hit AS H ON P.id = H.id
INNER JOIN levels AS L ON H.meter_id = L.id
INNER JOIN config AS F ON H.id =F.id;
```

Notice that I've taken the liberty to add aliases on your table names, this can simplify your queries alot.

To understand how joins work in MySQL, read about it [here in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html). A good tutorial about joins was written by Jeff Atwood, you can find it [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).